# Firebase Functions and CRA, .js files not found in static asset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I struggle on firebase functions does not load the static .js files, so my index.html stays white. Replacing the cra-index.html with a "non-js" index.html with a simple h1 works fine.
Locally, the index.html with javascript is loaded as well!

In my firebase functions index.js i used:

```
app.use(express.static("client/build/"));
```

due to the fact that a "non-js" index.html is served fine by:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html");
});
```

this cant be the problem.

My index.html js-refs looks like this:

```
    <script src="static/js/2.1ea6fe96.chunk.js"></script>
```

and my folderstructure looks like this:
[folderstructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFn5D.jpg)

Can someone help me out?
I am 100% sure that i made a mistake in referencing the .js files in the index.html but again, emulating the function by "firebase serve" locally works fine.
Does firebase functions require a special style of defining the paths?
Someone struggled on this too and can save some of my time?

Answer (score 1):

`firebase serve` locally [runs multiple “services”](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#emulate_your_project_using_local_http_functions) including Firebase Hosting and Firebase Cloud Functions.  It is Hosting that makes your CRA app available to the browser, not Cloud Functions.

Recognize that you are likely using several services:

- Hosting
- Cloud Functions
- Firestore (and/or Realtime Database…)

You have a few options:

- deploy to Cloud Functions and to Firebase Hosting
- deploy to Cloud Functions, run hosting locally (`firebase serve --only hosting`)
- deploy to Cloud Functions, host your CRA app in some other way (e.g. locally with `npm start`, or deploy it to a webserver somewhere)

There are also the [Firebase Emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) you might play with, now with a [new Emulator UI!](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/05/local-firebase-emulator-ui.html)!

Comment: I dont use Hosting. Using Firebase serve and calling the functions --> express --> api endpoint '/' lets the index.html render locally. Doing the same in the "real world" wont work, firebase doesnt load the .js files.